# Is there a definition of a r-interior similar to that of a r-neighborhood?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $r > 0$. Then,

(1) The $r$-neighborhood of a set $A$ is the set $N_r(A)$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p,q)<r$.

Is there a similar definition for a $r$-interior? Such as

(2?) The $r$-interior of a set $A$ is a set $I_r(A)$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p,q)<r$ implies $p \in A$.

That is, $I_r(A)$ contains all points such that an $r$ open ball is contained in $A$.

The main use of the definition is for this theorem:

(3?) If the is a $r>0$ such that $x_n$ is in the $r$-interior of a set $A$, then $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ implies $y_n$ is in $A$ for $n$ large enough.

Proof: We have a $N$ such that for $n > N$, $d(x_n , y_n) < r$, and therefore $y_n \in B$ for $n > N$.

Comment: So that $I_r(A)$ is the biggest subset $B$ making $N_r(B) \subseteq A$.

Comment: Yes, precisely. Is this a concept described anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "for some r > 0" is awkward and confusing.
Do you mean that for all r > 0, the r-interior of A,
I(A) = { x : B(x,r} subset A }?

No, I have not seen any use of it.  The r-nhood is used.
If A is bounded and r large, then I(A) is empty.

Comment: Modified my question so that the $r > 0$ part is not confusing.

Comment: Usually $I_r(A)$ empty for some $r$ is not really a problem. The main use of my definition is that if there exists a $r>0$ such that $x_n$ is in the $r$-interior of a set $A$, then $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$ implies $y_n$ is in $A$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Does $N(A)^c = I(A^c)?$